# Magento 2.3: Checkout page displays only `loading image` after checkout_index_index.xml was overridden in the custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, overrides, frontend, page-layouts

The checkout page now display loading image forever after I have overridden the  checkout_index_index.xml in the custom theme to remove `fax`field from the checkout page. Below is the screenshot showing the customized xml. Could you please point out the issue that might be causing endless loading image. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: fax field is default or you customised field on checkout page?

Comment: do you have any error at console?

Comment: @ Yasir Latif , no errors.

Comment: @chandresh chauhan, fax field is always there. I am now trying to remove it from the checkout page. I now could remove it but the Place Order button doesn't after this change. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps to remove the `fax` field in the checkout page

**Step-1**

Go to admin path

```
Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and
> Address Options > Show Fax > No
```

[image]

**Step-2**
You need to override checkout_index_index.xml.

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

And below Code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!--Remove fields-->
                                                                <item name="fax" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Run CLI Commands

```
 bin/magento cache:clean
 bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Hi, The first option offered by the Admin panel doesn't take any effect. Fax was default set to NO.

Comment: try 2nd steps....

Comment: what happened?@CodeForGood

Comment: None of the solutions could lead to a perfect situation as the final issue rests with Place Order button. Trying to see what is behind this.

Comment: I am accepting the second solution involving overrriding XML file because it removed the Fax text field in the first place.